# Remove leading NaN in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

How can I remove leading NaN's in pandas?

```
pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])
```

I want to remove only the first 3 NaN's from above, so the result should be:

```
pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 3])
```

Comment: `pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3][3:])` like this?

Comment: @clemtoy that was an example. I don't know how many leading NaN's I have

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is another method using pandas methods only:

```
In [103]:
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])
first_valid = s[s.notnull()].index[0]
s.iloc[first_valid:]

Out[103]:
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64
```

So we filter the series using `notnull` to get the first valid index. Then use `iloc` to slice the series

**EDIT**

As @ajcr has pointed out it is better to use the built-in method [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) as this does not return a temp series which I'm using to mask in the above answer, additionally using `loc` uses the index label rather than `iloc` which uses ordinal position which works for the general case where the index is not an int64Index:

```
In [104]:
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])
s.loc[s.first_valid_index():]

Out[104]:
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64
```

Comment: It works except the case where series is only nan values.first_valid_index will raise index error. To prevent this, I had to test all nan case before. **if not  ny.isnan(df.values).all()**

Comment: @JulienV true but that was never part of the OP's requirement, you could test if `first_valid_index()` returns `None` also

Comment: I believe `first_valid_index()` returns the actual index value not the index number... so you would want `.loc` instead of `.iloc`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree with @wkzhu, the example code fails if the index is a DatetimeIndex for example.. The general solution is I believe `s.loc[s.first_valid_index():]`

Comment: @wkzhu I've now updated my answer and I agree that `.loc` is better for the general case

Comment: @DavidWaterworth  I've now updated my answer and I agree that .loc is better for the general case

Answer (score 2):

**Find first non-nan index**

To find the index of the first non-nan item

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])

nans = s.apply(np.isnan)

first_non_nan = nans[nans == False].index[0] # get the first one
```

**Output**

```
s[first_non_nan:]
Out[44]:
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Two more approaches could be suggested here, assuming `A` as the input series.

Approach #1: With slicing -

```
A[np.where(~np.isnan(A))[0][0]:]
```

Approach #2: With masking -

```
A[np.maximum.accumulate(~np.isnan(A))]
```

Sample run -

```
In [219]: A = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3])

In [220]: A
Out[220]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64

In [221]: A[np.where(~np.isnan(A))[0][0]:]       # Approach 1
Out[221]: 
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64

In [222]: A[np.maximum.accumulate(~np.isnan(A))]  # Approach 2
Out[222]: 
3     1
4     2
5   NaN
6     3
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score -1):

To remove the leading `np.nan`:

```
tab = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan, 3]
pd.Series(tab[tab.index([n for n in tab if np.isnan(n)].pop(0)):])
```

Comment: I was hoping for a vectorized solution

Comment: I think a list comprehension will still loop in the Python interpreter instead of using vectorized operations in the numerical libs

Comment: @clemtoy as bakkal said, [n for n in tab ...] is not vectorized. Also, you must use `np.isnan(n)` to test for NaN, `n != np.nan` doesn't work (try `np.nan == np.nan` in a console)

Comment: @bakkal Ah ok, I wrongly interpreted 'vectorized' sorry.